# Typecasting Error

Tags: c++

I am trying to typecast a string to an integer for a project however I keep getting invalid casting errors. I've tried several methods for casting however the same error keeps occurring. What am I doing wrong and how could I fix this? Thanks! My code is below.

```
Quarterback::Quarterback(string userInput){
    string tempWord;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++){
        if (userInput[i] == ','){
            count++;
            if (count == 1){
                qbName = tempWord;
                tempWord = "";
            }
            if (count == 2){
                passCompletions = (int)tempWord;  //Issue occurs here
                tempWord = "";
        }
        else
            tempWord += userInput[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're doing wrong is that a `std::string` cannot be converted to an `int`. That's it. The End.

Comment: That's because you can't typecast a `string` to an `int`. The compiler is (trying to) tell you you can't typecast a `string` to an `int`. The thing you are doing wrong is trying to typecast a `string` to an `int`. Was the compiler's error message unclear?

Comment: It's best not to use C-style casts in C++ - this is a C-style cast, with the round brackets: `int x = (int)notAnInt;`. Use `int x = static_cast<int>(notAnInt);` instead - it makes your intention clearer. However that won't help you cast a string to an int. You cannot cast a string to an int - has anyone mentioned this yet?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to convert an object to a primitive variable. That is not possible.  You need to use stoi() function.

Answer (score 2):

you can cast every character of the string to int .every character is the integer value of its ascii code .the string class has the [] operator to access every character.
 you can change this part of your code like that:

```
if (count == 2){
for(int i=0;i<tempWord.size();i++){
            passCompletions += (tempWord[i]-48)*pow(10,(tempWord.size()-i)); 
 //48 is the ascii of '0' and  this :(tempWord[i]-48) is the characters value and pow(10,(tempWord.size()-i)); is for setting the priority of the number for example 4567 the first character is 4 and your integer variable should be summed with 4000 and next time is 5 and it should be summed with 5*100.......
            tempWord = "";
}
    }
```